# Merge tags: 'file-copy' and 'file-management'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I just stumbled upon the [file-copy](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-copy) tag which, IMHO, should be merged into [file-management](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-management) and then should be made a synonym to the latter. There are a few questions carrying this tag with no clear relation to it (which I will now go and clean up), everything else should go along fine. Maybe some will better fit into [file-transfer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-transfer) or [sync](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync), so I will take care for those as well.

Affected questions summa-summarum: 15 right now, after my cleanup probably 10 or less left for the merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, thanks for the cleanup!

Comment: Thanks for the merge! Cleanup just completed. Can you also merge-in the tag `copying` (just detected while cleaning up; about 8 entries left there)? Not sure if a synonym is needed here; it may not hurt, but might be confusing (copy files or copy-paste text?).

Comment: @Izzy Most of those have been retagged to `copy-paste` and I created the synonym `text-copy` for it.  `copying` should fade away now :)

Comment: Ah, great -- so you can ignore my corresponding question on chat :) THANX! Excellent.